# Alternative to rename_function in php7.3

Tags: php, function, rename

I need to use `rename_function` into php7.3 under Debian 10 Buster.
I'm trying to install *apd* library but when I run the install command I receive the following error:

```
# pecl install apd

pear/apd requires PHP (version >= 5.0.0RC3-dev, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.3.6-1+0~20190531112735.39+stretch~1.gbp6131b7
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Is there any alternative to `rename_function` in php7.3?

Comment: [That extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/apd) is abandoned since 2004 so you need a PHP version around that age.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative to `rename_function` in php7.3?